# Javascript -How to run independent multi host with same port?

Tags: javascript, node.js, server

I have 2 applications then i want to run  independent 2 hosts with same port (if app1 crash/stop, app2 will be continue or vice versa.)

Comment: You need to have 2 interfaces. Each node instance bind one.

Answer (score 0):

You can't have two things running on the exact same port - how would the system determine which one to route data to?

Instead, they should run on different ports that aren't exposed to the public (say, 8080 and 8081), and then a separate public facing application (running on, for example, port 80) that routes things to the right place. This sort of setup is is called a [reverse proxy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_proxy), and it's incredibly common.

You could write your own in Node if you really wanted to (at the simplest level, it's basically just a HTTP server that forwards requests on to a different port/IP), but generally people tend to use either [NGINX](https://www.nginx.com) or [Apache](https://httpd.apache.org/), as they've proven themselves to be really solid.